# Socket.io 2.3.0 timestamps on connection and discconect

Tags: node.js, socket.io, timestamp

how can I get the time when a socket connects and disconnects in nodejs?
`io.sockets.on('connection', ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using these three functions for various uses within my project although you can just grab the timestamp using Date() and convert it later on.

```
function getLocaleDateTimeString() { // date and time
    var timestamp = new Date();
    const offset = timestamp.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; // milliseconds
    const local = new Date(timestamp.getTime() - offset);
    return (local).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ");
}

function getLocaleDateString() { // date only
    var timestamp = new Date();
    const offset = timestamp.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; // milliseconds
    const local = new Date(timestamp.getTime() - offset);
    return (local).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
}

function getLocaleTimeString() { // time only
    var timestamp = new Date();
    const offset = timestamp.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; // milliseconds
    const local = new Date(timestamp.getTime() - offset);
    return (local).toISOString().slice(11, 19);
}
```